# How can I work with Windows security groups without knowing their localized names in advance?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I've searched around online but can't find what I'm after.  Basically, during an install, we fire off a separate executable that basically brute forces a few folders to be read/write enabled for the user group "EVERYONE".

Now, the person that wrote this never took into consideration system language.  I had a call with a customer in France that kept failing installation because "EVERYONE" isn't what we would expect.

I'm after an API call to Windows that would return a security group name which would be "safe" to use in a localized environment.  Essentially I'm looking to safely edit this code so instead of hardcoding in "EVERYONE", we call a function instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fundamental mistake here is not so much the use of `EVERYONE`, but rather that the code is using names at all. Instead of using names you should use the [well-known SIDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330). In your case you need `S-1-1-0`.

Comment: This blog post from the Jedi guys may help: [What is a SID?](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/03/10/what-is-a-sid/)